# Removing bottom padding forces left and right whitespace

Tags: css, wordpress, removing-whitespace, visual-composer

http://www.davenport.gallery/dev/portfolio-item/passion/

The two rows are to occupy 50vh - leaving not space at the bottom or left/right.

It needs to be full-width and full-height.

However when I remove:

```
margin-lg-30b: padding-bottom:30px;
```

This creates unwanted white space left and right (about 5px). I need it to be full width with no bottom padding and no scroll bar.

I tried adding:

```
html, body{ overflow:hidden!important;}
```

and this creates the same whitespace issue.

How can I remove the 30px padding at the bottom but still maintain the 100% width?

Thank you!

Comment: a *bottom* padding creating *left and right* space?

Comment: Removing the bottom padding creates the left and right whitespace.

Comment: remove the margin for `margin-lg-30b` and close the inspector it will be rendered in full-width

Comment: This does not work. The whitespace is still there right and left. My inspector is undocked so not affecting browser

Comment: Have you set your parent body margin to 0? If not then it will automatically add some margin.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] within the question itself, you cannot just paste a link to your site as links rot and once you have fixed the problem, future visitors to this site won't have any reference to what the problem was (this is meant to be a repository for future visitors to see problems and solutions) - see [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Thank you Pete. Hope your knickers aren’t in too much of a twist. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove class **.margin-lg-30b** from element
**container clearfix no-padd portfolio-single-content margin-lg-30b**.

Comment: This does not work. The whitespace is still there right and left

Comment: I think you test it in developer tools

edit **section** element and its first child div

Comment: if you test it with developer tools the scroll bar width will be calculated in your script, so try it in your code